# How do I make a Python installation redistributable?

Tags: python

### Background

I want to distribute a set of **development** tools with a setup created with Inno Setup. The tools I want to include are:

- Python embeddable package
- A list of pre-downloaded packages for Python (including `pip`)
- Node.js
- Git

The reason I want to prefetch all the components of the suite is that the target machine where I'd be running the setup could have network restrictions (e.g., proxies, firewalls, etc.).

The steps I follow to make the Python bundle are:

1. Download the Python embeddable package (see https://www.python.org/ftp/python/).
2. Unzip the archive in the `assets\PythonXY` directory (where `X` and `Y` are the major and minor version numbers of Python).
3. Download the `get-pip.py` script (see https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py).
4. Run the `get-pip.py` script with the `assets\PythonXY\python.exe` executable.
5. Install the packages defined in a `requirements.txt` file.
6. Uncomment the `import site` line from the `assets\PythonXY\pytho312._pth` file.

Then, the Inno Setup compiler takes all the files inside the `assets` directory where all the tools are located, including Node.js and Git.

---

### Problem

When executing the setup on the target host, it uncompresses all the files in the given directory and also appends the respective directories of each tool to the `Path` environment variable of the user.

At this point in the target host, I can:

- Run `python` from CMD.
- Run `node` from CMD.

But trying to call `pip` or any script coming from the installed packages for Python gives me the following error message:

```bash
Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"C:\Repositories\RobotFrameworkRuntime\assets\Python312\python.exe"  "C:\Users\xuandogg\AppData\Roaming\Test Automation Runtime\Python312\Scripts\pip.exe" ': The system cannot find the file specified.
```

As you can probably see, the Python referenced executable is using the path of the `assets` directory where I compile the setup.

I think it has something to do with the shebangs of the packages, but I don't know how to fix it, or even if there's another way of achieving the Python redistribution.

---

### Actual Questions

To sum up:

- **Is there any way to fix the installation of `pip` and all the Python packages when relocating the Python embeddable package?**
- **If not, is there another way of achieving the redistribution of Python with custom packages preinstalled?**

Comment: Cannot you simply ship a container image that contains everything to the client? I don't think using Inno Setup here is the right approach.

Comment: @LexLi I know it may not be the best approach, but: 1) We are not allowed to use Docker (company constraint) and 2) We want to give the simplest solution possible to the final user, so they just have to click [Install].

Comment: I know only that the exes in `Scripts` have one or more entries in a string table which control what is called by the exe. Somewhere in the source of distutils or setuptools the code is buried to generate those executables.

Comment: You will need to reproduce your working software on a plain-vanilla Windows machine (I would suggest a VM so you can use snapshots) by making needed the needed modifications on the system by hand. Once you have figured out all of the details, then you can consider how to automate the process using Inno Setup. (This is not really an Inno Setup question, in reality.)